# Break Table Rows CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive, break

I am trying to make 3 tables horizontally(named table 1, 2, 3) placed on Desktop(Done). For mobile(need your help here), I want to make table 2 go under table 1 and so on, table 3 under table 2. Like the example I will be adding.

```html
<table class="calculator">
  <tr>
        <th class="col1"></th>
        <th class="col2"></th>
        <th class="col3"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>INSERIR VENDA</td>
    <td>DOCUMENTACAO COMERCIAL</td>
    <td>INSERIR RECLAMACAO</td>
    <td>FAQs</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>GESTAO ENCOMENDAS</td>
    <td>ESTADO FINANCIAMENTO</td>
    <td>GESTAO RECLAMACOES</td>
    <td>QUESTÕES PARA FAQs</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>PLANNING ENTREGAS</td>
    <td>REGISTO FINANCIAMENTO</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>STATUS</td>
    <td>PEDIR APOIO VENDA</td>
    <td>VIATURA SERVICO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>DOCUMENTACAO EM FALTA</td>
    <td>ESTADO DO PEDIDO APOIO</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This looks something like this: https://codepen.io/dolive/pen/ExPpbwg

and I want to turn it into this when screen gets lower res, making it a responsive table and breaking columns down:

[mobile responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OK2Nk.png)

Link : [enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OK2Nk.png)

Do you belive this is possible ? Could anyone possibly help a "noob" out? Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Do the rows in the "mobile responsive" image need to be able to be collapsable? It's not really clear why it should be a/one table element. Is it for example possible to make three separated table elements? That would make the responsiveness easier.

Comment: Yes it is possible, I have quickly set it up here. 
https://codepen.io/dolive/pen/ZEQjaVO

Comment: @Remi I have updated again with my CSS, can you take a look? Please don't judge hahaha I know its bad.   How can I reduce the space between tables on mobile? I am not  being able to do that :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the example you're giving I'm not sure how you want to display the data itself (other than the direction of the columns).

So here is how you'd use CSS to stack the columns:

```css
/*
 On mobile devices the divs are already vertically stacked,
 so only on larger screen sizes they will have to be horizontally stacked
*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .grid__container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid__container">
  <div class="grid__item">
    <p>First block</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item">
    <p>Second block</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item">
    <p>Third block</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Motivation:**

A common practice is to start with the mobile view and then gradually enhance the site as the screen size grows. ([UXPin source](https://www.uxpin.com/studio/blog/a-hands-on-guide-to-mobile-first-design/) on mobile first design)

In the example CSS grid is used. CSS grid gives you a lot of flexibility 'stacking' the divs for different screen sizes. (You could even change the order of the divs if you'd like.) ([CSS-tricks source](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/))

Usually you don't want to change the CSS display property of a table *itself* because then you lose **structural markup**. ([w3.org source](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/)) This is troublesome for accessibility. ([w3.org source](https://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/accessibility))

768px is a breakpoint. That is a point in which you want your columns to change direction. ([w3schools.org source](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_media_query_breakpoints.asp))

Comment: Thank you for your help @Remi 
I managed to make it work.